# Filter only gyms to show in GMSAutocompleteViewController

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-places, gmsautocomplete

Gym is present in supported types as mentioned on Google's site.

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types.

I just can't seem to figure out how to filter specific types to show results.

So far I have tried:

```
    let field = GMSPlaceField(rawValue: UInt(GMSPlaceField.types.rawValue))
    autocompleteController.placeFields = field!
    let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
    filter.type = kGMSPlaceTypeGym
    autocompleteController.autocompleteFilter = filter
```

Comment: What have you tried? Showing some code will probably help you get an answer.

Comment: @Marcio check now